# Actionbar sherlock icon resolutions for different screen size?

Tags: android, icons, actionbarsherlock

I've a problem regarding stretching icons on actionbar sherlock.
please guide me about different icon sizes regarding actionbar.

Comment: can you show some images or code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution here:
http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html#action-bar

Thanks all for the support!

Answer (score 0):

72 * 72 image are use in actionbar sherlock icon for all screens use